# Can I use FontAwesome fonts with my own custom CSS files?

Tags: legal, mit-license

I want to use the WebFont icon library FontAwesome (FA) for all the icons in my project. They are using SIL OFL 1.1 for the fonts and MIT License for the source files. My problem is that, I want to use the FA fonts in my project, however I don't want to be tied to their CSS files. Is it possible for me to use the fonts with my own custom CSS styles, without having any dependence on the FA's CSS files. I don't even mind endorsing the project on my website, but if even do that, I want to only endorse the art not the code.

FontAwesome License: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/license/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use those fonts with your own CSS files.

The licenses used by FontAwesome allow you to create derived works, and that also gives you the right to delete files that you don't need.

Licensing wise, the implications are:

- If you delete everything that is licensed under the MIT license (everything in the `font-awesome/css`, `font-awesome/less` and `font-awesome/scss` folders), you can also delete all references to the MIT license itself.
- If you make modifications to the files licensed under the SIL OFL (the files under `font-awesome/fonts`), you may need to change the name of the font as it is presented to the user. I haven't checked if they made the font name reserved.
- The fonts may not be sold separately, so if you separate the fonts from the rest of FontAwesome and you sell your software, you should ensure that the fonts are distributed in the same package to reduce the risk of violating that requirement.